# Sourcing the code

Tags: r, rstudio

If my .R file name is too large, or the location of that file is (name ) is too big.

I observed that If I hit the return key in between the location it is throwing an error.

Is there any way to writing the file location in two lines while sourcing it?

Thank you.

Comment: That sounds like it should be an RStudio bug report

Comment: Can you post an example of the code that's throwing the error? Specifically, which error?

Comment: Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `paste0` to break down the path.

If you want to source the following file:

```
"/home/user/work_dir/my_project/source_file.R"
```

Then you can break the path by using:

```
source(paste0("/home/user/",
              "work_dir/my_project/", 
              "source_file.R"
              )
       )
```